# Partial Universes and the Axioms of $ZF$ Set Theory Without Choice

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

In [his Senior Thesis](https://www.math.washington.edu/Undergrad/Handbook/Senior%20Theses/SamuelCoskey_June2003.pdf), Samuel Coskey answered the question of which axioms of $ZFC$ hold at each stage of the cumulative hierarchy.  Here is the list of his results:

> Axioms that always hold:  Extensionality, Foundation, Union, Axiom Schema of Separation, Choice.
>
> Axioms that hold in $V_{\alpha}$ iff $\alpha$$\gt$0:  Empty Set.
>
> Axioms that hold in $V_{\alpha}$ iff $\alpha$$\gt$$\omega$:  Infinity.
>
> Axioms that hold at limit ordinals:  Power Set, Pairing.
>
> Axioms that hold at inaccessible cardinals: Axiom Schema of Replacement.

My question is simply this:

> What changes (if anything) in these results if Choice is dropped?

Comment: @MartinSleziak:  Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you drop choice, then of course choice is no longer in the "always holds" category, but there's nothing to determine at what level of the cumulative hierarchy it first fails.  The first failure of choice could occur just a few levels past $\omega$, or it could occur far beyond the first inaccessible cardinal.  (The vagueness of "a few levels" comes from the details of how you formulate choice; formulations that are equivalent in ZF need not be equivalent when basic things like pairing are unavailable.)

As far as I can see, the only other thing that might change in the results you quoted is that definitions of inaccessibility that are equivalent in ZFC are no longer equivalent in ZF, so you need to be careful about which version of the definition you use.  For more details than you probably want about various definitions of inaccessibility, see my joint paper with Ioanna Dimitriou and Benedikt Löwe, "Inaccessible caridnals without the axiom of choice" [Fundamenta Mathematicae 194 (2007) 179-189, [DOI: 10.4064/fm194-2-3](http://dx.doi.org/10.4064/fm194-2-3)].

Comment: @AndrenBlass:  This is helpful.  Could you give an example of a formulation of Choice which would fail, say, after $\omega_1$ in $ZF$?  Is there a hierarchy of failures of formulations of choice as you go further up the cumulative hierarchy of $ZF$?  What would those be (and would those results be in the paper you cited)?

Comment: Also, apologies regarding the typo in the misspelling of your name in the previous comment.

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin How about e.g. "$V_{\omega_2}$ is well-orderable"? This could fail while still having $V_{\omega_1}$ satisfy AC. This is a standard exercise in symmetric submodels: if $\mathbb{P}$ is $\vert V_\kappa\vert^+$-closed, then forcing with $\mathbb{P}$ doesn't change the first $\kappa$-many levels of the cumulative hierarchy, so any nontrivial symmetric submodel of such a forcing extension will introduce a failure of choice above $\kappa$ while preserving choice below.

Comment: @NoahSchweber:  Yes, that example is very helpful.  Can one infer from your example that one can force $AC$ to hold at $V_{\omega_1}$ while force '$V_{\kappa}$ is well-orderable' to fail for all$\kappa$$\gt$$\omega_1$?  Since in the absence of $AC$ various formulations of $AC$ may not be equivalent; in your example, might other formulations of $AC$ still hold at $V_{\omega_2}$?

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin It's consistent with ZF that $V_{\omega_1}$ is well-orderable while $V_{\omega_1+1}$ is not. And there's nothing special here about $\omega_1$ (except that it's an infinite ordinal). Starting from a universe satisfying ZFC and an infinite ordinal $\alpha$ therein, one can force a failure of well-orderability in $V_{\alpha+1}$ without adding any new elements to $V_\alpha$ (and therefore without damaging the well-orderability of $V_\alpha$).

Comment: What about the axiom of infinity?  Without choice there are multiple *inequivalent* options for how one defines infinity.  Will all natural versions of the axiom still hold at $V_{\alpha}$ for $\alpha>\omega$?

Comment: @PaceNielsen since $V_\alpha$ contains $\omega$ for all $\alpha > \omega$, the usual Dedekind-ish versions of the axiom of infinity are all equivalent. As Andreas said, this is not true if really basic things like pairing fail, but then you probably don't know what $V_\alpha$ is either.

Comment: @PaceNielsen It seems to me that various formulations of the axiom of infinity will hold in $V_\alpha$ for any $\alpha>\omega$. The only exceptions would be versions that depend very strongly on pairing (as Francois mentioned) and ones that essentially build in some form of choice (like calling a set infinite iff it has a nonprincipal ultrafilter).  "Reasonable" definitions of "infinite" should, in particular, say that $\omega$ is infinite, so there will be an infinite set in $V_\alpha$ for any $\alpha>\omega$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass yes, I completely agree. It's hard (but probably not impossible, as you have often reminded me) to think of a way to say "$x = V_\alpha$" without pairing when $\alpha > \omega$. (And many thanks for the reminders!)

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais We probably don't need to worry about defining $V_\alpha$ in the absence of pairing; I understand the question as referring to the $V_\alpha$'s as defined in the ambient universe, where full ZF is available. The pairing issue arises if someone formulates the axiom of infinity in a way that presupposes too much pairing.

Comment: @AndreasBlass:  I just wanted to check something.  In light of your's and Francois Dorais' comments regarding the 'failure of the Axiom of Pairing(?)' in $ZF$ without choice,  does Coskey's theorem, "If $\alpha$ is limit, the Pairing Axiom holds in $V_{\alpha}$" still hold in $ZF$ without choice?  If not , what is the smallest limit ordinal at which Pairing fails (or is that limit ordinal model-dependent)?

Comment: The fact that pairing holds in $V_\alpha$ for all limit $\alpha$ doesn't use the axiom of choice, just the definition of $V_\alpha$, basic facts about ordinals, and a tiny bit of ZF. If $x,y\in V_\alpha$ then, because $\alpha$ is a limit, $x,y\in V_\beta$ for some $\beta<\alpha$, so $\{x,y\}$ is an element of $V_{\beta+1}\subseteq V_\alpha$, and it clearly does (in $V_\alpha$) what the pairing axiom requires.